# Взаимодействие между модулями (приложениями) на сервере приложений

Tags: glassfish, ejb

Столкнулся с проблемой взаимодействия между модулями на сервере приложений.
В наличии:

- Сервлет (appA)
- **EJB** модуль (appB).

Из сервлета обращаюсь через удаленный бизнес-интерфейс к **EJB**. Могу получить простой тип в виде ответа (`String` например), но не могу получить объект класса (`class Employee`). **EJB** использует **JPA**. Employee - это Entity.
Дело в том, что все это работает если обращаться к **EJB** из простого консольного клиента, но не работает из сервлета.

Что бы это могло быть? Использую ***GlassFish 4.1***

Workaround нашелся: 

 persistence.xml 

 property name="eclipselink.weaving.fetchgroups" value="false"

Comment: что значит не можете получить? какая ошибка?

Comment: Ошибок нет! Вызов EJB метода как-будто возвращает объект (Employee@7cae4a3). Но при обращении к методу полученного объекта (getId() например) возвращает null. Значит ли это что десериализация прошла неуспешно (Employee implements Serializable)?

Comment: А случайно не включена lazy loading?

Comment: Тут загрузка непосредственно строки из таблицы. @Basic(optional =) не использую. Да и потом все работает при обращении из внешнего клиента.

Comment: а что за внешний клиент? он работает в том же контейнере, что и EJB?

Comment: Под внешним клиентом имею ввиду простое консольное приложение для проверки  EJB. Вне сервера приложений, вне контейнера.

Comment: а как клиент получает EntityManager? и как EJB находит?

Comment: В сервлете сам EJB я получить могу. Могу выполнить методы которые обрабатывают данные из базы и возвращают простой ответ в виде числа или строки (найти максимум например). Проблема проявляется когда пытаюсь вернуть Entity.

Comment: InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
  HelloRemote bean = (HelloRemote) ic.lookup("com.HelloRemote");
  Employee emp = bean.getEmp(55);
     
      System.out.println( " got object " + emp.getFirstName() );

Comment: В сервлете пробовал по-разному. И через контекст и через нотации. Без разницы.
@EJB (lookup="com.HelloRemote")
HelloRemote bean;

Comment: а если перед тем как вернуть объект из EJB вызвать getId() и выдать его в лог например. после этого Id в сервлете будет доступно?

Comment: Попробовал! Не помогло.
    public Employee getEmp(int id){
      Employee res = em.find(Employee.class, id);
      System.out.println( "res out " + res.getId() );
        return res;
    }
Запись из лога сервера:
2016-12-27T23:02:35.591+0400|Info: res out 55

Comment: Ура! Все понял! :))) Ответ: <property name="eclipselink.weaving.fetchgroups" value="false"/>